# AWS Amplify can't get access token after authorization with Google

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

When authorizing via Google in the react app, the `idToken` parameter is equal to `undefiend` for such a call, although the value of the `accessToken` is indicated in the `storage`. So how can I get `accessToken` in this way?

When authorizing through a password I can get a token in this way:

`const authToken = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens?.idToken?.toString();`

[log of `await fetchAuthSession()` after oauth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NRYs.png)

Comment: Is it undefend or undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just this to get accessToken

`const accessToken = (await fetchAuthSession()).authSession.tokens?.accessToken?.toString()`

This was my mistake, because the first time I tried to get a token it was not valid for some reason, apparently I missed something somewhere then. Hope this will help to someone.

Also keep in mind that when authorizing through a password and oauz, the token can be obtained using different methods (as in the description of the problem and as in this answer)